# References to Views/Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server-2000

How can I find out what other views/stored procedures are using a specific view/stored procedure? Thanks Lennie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are excellent tools out there that help you with this - e.g. Red-Gate's [SQL Dependency Tracker](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Dependency_Tracker/index.htm). Well worth the investment - finding dependencies is a challenge you'll face over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

[sp_depends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189487.aspx) will:

> Displays information about database
>   object dependencies, such as the views
>   and procedures that depend on a table
>   or view, and the tables and views that
>   are depended on by the view or
>   procedure.

Note:

> This feature will be removed in a
>   future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in
>   new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use
>   this feature. Use
>   `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` and
>   `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`
>   instead.

As @marc mentioned, Redgate's SQL Dependency Tracker is worth the investment.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest SQL way with no 3rd party tools is to search the view/proc/udf definition

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE definition LIKE '%WhatToLookFor%"
```

For SQL Server 2000 (as per your tag), use `syscomments`

The internal dependency tracking of SQL Server is notoriously, er, shit, at least before sys.sql_expression_dependencies (related to Mitch's answer). And definitely in SQL Server 2000.